# textarea's rows, and cols attribute in CSS

Tags: css, styling

I'd like to set the `textarea`'s `rows` and `cols` attributes via CSS.

How would I do this in CSS?

Comment: A when to use which question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/is-it-better-to-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attr

Comment: Also see: [textarea: styling with css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_with_css), [styling web forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Styling_web_forms), and [textarea spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-textarea-cols)

Comment: I guess it's important to realize that the `textarea` is treated as a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), with intrinsic dimensions (similar to an `img`), as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_with_css).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`width` and `height` are used when going the css route.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Setting Width and Height on Textareas</title>
        <style>
            .comments { width: 300px; height: 75px }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="comments"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per user2928048's answer below, if you use "em" rather than "px" then you can specify the width and height in characters as you would with 'rows' and 'cols' attributes. Even works with IE6 I believe.

Comment: While I agree with using `em` for specifying the height, I doubt that it can be used to specify the width. It _might_ work with monospace fonts (after figuring out the width:height ratio of the characters and modifying the width value correspondingly), and that's it. Except monospace, character widths are not fixed, so I don't think `em` or `cols` attribute can help when specifying the width.

Comment: I might be wrong, but px didn't work for me; em did.

Answer (score 367):

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

It is equivalent to:

```
textarea {
    height: 4em;
    width: 50em;
}
```

where 1em is equivalent to the current font size, thus make the text area 50 chars wide.
[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: To be more exact, you need to take `padding` and `line-height` in account. Say you have a padding of half an em at the top and at the bottom and a line-height of 1.2em, then the height for 4 rows would be 1 + 4 * 1.2 =  5.8em.

Comment: @nalply your solution is correct. The problem is 4em = 4 x font-size which neither factors the padding nor line-height

Comment: If you have property box-sizing:content-box; you will not have to worry about padding, so you remain only with line height.

Comment: Nice @nalply, thanks for the approach. Adding a little to your answer, the calc() CSS3 function can ease the width/height computation: say I have a textarea with padding-top and padding-bottom 4px, and I want it to be 3 rows high, the height would be `height: calc(3em + 8px);`.

Comment: While `rows` attribute is (somewhat) reliable, I wouldn't rely on `cols` attribute unless I'm using monospace fonts on the textarea. See @AlexanderScholz's [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovjz6t54/).

Comment: @akinuri the default behavior is to use a monospaced font in a textarea.

Comment: The [HTLM spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-textarea-element-2) mentions the effective width of the textarea as `size*avg+sbw` where `size` is `cols` (or 20), `avg` is the average font width, `sbw` is the scroll bar width.

Comment: in 2024 use `height: 4lh;` // line-height

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you can.  I always go with height and width.

```
textarea{
width:400px;
height:100px;
}
```

the nice thing about doing it the CSS way is that you can completely style it up.  Now you can add things like:

```
textarea{
width:400px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't.

Besides, that isnt what CSS is for anyway. CSS is for styling and HTML is for markup.

Comment: CSS is for styling the visual representation of an element. This includes the width and height of a textarea.

Comment: They are not the same, the browser takes into account the height of text on each row including `line-height`, `padding` on the container (not calculating a height based on `box-sizing`), even taking into account different aspect ratios of fonts used to ensure the textbox displays the set number of rows of text which you cannot achieve by using css height.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post a demo using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for setting rows/height, since no one did.

```css
body {
  /* page default */
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

textarea {
  /* demo related */
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  
  /* rows related */
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 3px;
}

textarea.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea.rows-5 {
  /* height: calc(font-size * line-height * rows); */
  height: calc(1em * 1.5 * 5);
}

textarea.border-box.rows-5 {
  /* height: calc(font-size * line-height * rows + padding-top + padding-bottom + border-top-width + border-bottom-width); */
  height: calc(1em * 1.5 * 5 + 3px + 3px + 1px + 1px);
}
```

```html
<p>height is 2 rows by default</p>

<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>

<p>height is 5 now</p>

<textarea class="rows-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>

<p>border-box height is 5 now</p>

<textarea class="border-box rows-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
```

If you use large values for the paddings (e.g. greater than 0.5em), you'll start to see the text that overflows the content(-box) area, and that might lead you to think that the height is not exactly x rows (that you set), but it is. To understand what's going on, you might want to check out [The box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) and [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) pages.