# use cols/rows or style-width/height to specify dimensions of textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

what is considered best practice when specifying the dimensions of an HTML textarea? only using cols/rows (which i think are mandatory with html strict 4.01) or specifying width and height using css properties?
or even setting cols/rows for validity and then overriding the actual size using css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this question: [Should I size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/how-do-you-size-a-textarea)

I agree with the top answer. You use rows/cols in case CSS is not supported; if width or height are specified using CSS, they override the value derived from rows/cols.