# Height of textarea does not match the rows in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, textarea

The textarea's `rows` attribute does not match the number of lines in Firefox. For instance:

```
<textarea rows=4 cols=40>
1
2
3
4
this line is visible in FF
</textarea>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7zXs/6/

How can I fix this issue? The textarea should only display 4 lines (instead of 5) for `rows=4`.

Comment: Do I understand right that by 'not visible' you mean that the user has to scroll down? if so just change 'rows=5'. Otherwise please explain what 'not visible' means.

Comment: @Martin I mean what you mentioned. but that line should not appear according to w3s: Sets the height of the text area (in rows)

Comment: Actually, **W3C** states »This attribute specifies the number of visible text lines.« No idea what w3s should be or where that quote comes from. Same content, though.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp

Comment: W3Schools is an unreliable resource. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: The try just simply to set using css the height. there is an answer like that. just play with the numbers and see what fits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firefox always adds an extra line after the textfield. If you want it to have a constant height, use CSS, e.g.:

```
textarea {
    height: 5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7zXs/7/

**EDIT:**
You can also use the [`@-moz-document url-prefix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document) CSS extension to target only the Firefox browser. Example

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    textarea {
        height: 5em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 88):

There are lot of answers but wasn't suitable for me:

- CSS rule (`height: 5em;`) is not flexible enoutgh because it completely overrides `rows` attribute
- And I don'n want to use JavaScript

There is a "bug": [TEXTAREA incorrectly applying ROWS= and COLS=](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33654)

**So here is my solution:**

*FF adds height to the TextArea to reserve place for scroll-bars.*

I don't need horizontal scroll bar so it helps with fixing the issue: following css rule can be added to textarea:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

[Here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywvat/1/). It works even with `rows=1`.

Comment: Setting the overflow works perfectly for me, thanks! I think FF making room for the scrollbar explains the discrepancy.

Comment: For me I also had to set `line-height` and `font-size` to 1em and then all 3 browsers looked identical.

Comment: .. and `overflow-y: hidden;` "fixes" Firefox for me, but Chrome seems to keep one space for the vertical scrollbar nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the height by using JavaScript (or hard-code a height of `4x1.2 = 4.8em`).

Example (JQuery), fix the issue for each textarea:

```
$("textarea").each(function(){
    var lineHeight = parseFloat($(this).css("line-height"));
    var lines = $(this).attr("rows")*1 || $(this).prop("rows")*1;
    $(this).css("height", lines*lineHeight);
});
```

The value of the `line-height` CSS property equals the height of each line ("row"). So, when you've defined `row`, this code will fix the height.

When the `rows` attribute is not set, the code will have a look at the default value (`.prop("rows")`).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem once and i couldn't use CSS, so JavaScript is the only way: Here's the Mootools and jQuery ways to do this:

Mootools:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
if (Browser.firefox) {
    $$('textarea[rows]').each(function(el) {
        if (!el.retrieve('ffRowsFixed')) {
            var rows = el.get('rows').toInt();
            if (rows > 1) el.set('rows', (rows - 1));
            el.store('ffRowsFixed', true);
        }
    });
}
});
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
     $('textarea[rows]').each(function(i, el) {
         if (!$(el).data('ffRowsFixed')) {
             var rows = parseInt($(el).attr('rows'));
             if (rows > 1) {
                 $(el).attr('rows', (rows - 1));
             }
             $(el).data('ffRowsFixed', true);
         }
     });
}
});
```

It will check if the browser is firefox, if it is, it will check if the rows have been corrected already, and if not they will get fixed.

Comment: does not fix textarea in case desired rows = 1.

Comment: $.browser was removed since jQuery 1.9.0, to complicate the life of developers just a bit more.