# Textarea overflow:auto difference in height

Tags: html, css, firefox, textarea

Following code renders a textarea which should have 3 visible rows:

```
<textarea id="txtInput" rows="3" cols="20" style="overflow:auto"></textarea>
```

However, in Firefox (version 20.0.1), 4 rows are shown instead of 3.

See also http://jsfiddle.net/KxXsS/

How can I fix this?

Comment: was this perhaps a bug in firefox 20? Cannot reproduce in firefox 23.

Comment: @bwoebi Just tried in 23, and same problem.

Comment: then it's maybe a windows-only problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height of textarea does not match the rows in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695945/height-of-textarea-does-not-match-the-rows-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox adds an extra lines after the textfields. You can fix this with CSS :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    textarea {
        height: 4em;
    }
}
```

The `@-moz...`is for mozilla specific rule, the url-prefix rule applies the rule to any page whose URL starts with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How can we specify a particular styling for other browsers in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KxXsS/1/)

```css
textarea {
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtInput" rows="3" cols="20" style="overflow:auto"></textarea>
```

Hope this helps.