# Control the size TextArea widget look in django admin

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I managed to override the look of a `TextArea` Widget in the django admin interface with two different ways:

#### using formfield_overrides

in `admin.py`:

```
class RulesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(
                       attrs={'rows': 1,
                              'cols': 40})},
}

...
admin.site.register(Rules, RulesAdmin)
```

This way is a bit of an overkill, since it will change all the TextField for that
model.

#### with a custom form:

in `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from TimePortal.models import Rules


class RulesModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rules
        widgets = {
            'parameters': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 1}),
   }
```

in `admin.py`

```
from AppName.forms import RulesModelForm

class RulesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = RulesModelForm
```

Both solutions resize the `TextArea`. However in both solutions the actual size of the 
text area is more than 1 row (actually 2 rows). Here is how the rendered HTML looks like:

```
    <div class="form-row field-parameters">
            <div>
                <label for="id_parameters" class="required">Parameters:</label>
                <textarea id="id_parameters" rows="1" cols="30" name="parameters">{}</textarea> 
           <p class="help">Enter a valid Python Dictionary</p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And here is a screentshot:

[image: Form]

According to [W3C referecnce for text area](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp):

> The size of a textarea can also be specified by the CSS height and width properties.

So, my questions are:

- Is django's own css theme is the responsible here for the "odd"
  behavior of this widget?
- Can some suggest a way to solve this issue?

Comment: I've tested your code, it actually works, shows me a textarea with 1 visible row, rendered as `<textarea cols="40" id="my_id" name="my_field" rows="1">...</textarea>`. May be this is a browser specific thing?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a browser-specific problem.

According to the thread [Height of textarea does not match the rows in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695945/height-of-textarea-does-not-match-the-rows-in-firefox):

> Firefox always adds an extra line after the textfield. If you want it
>   to have a constant height, use CSS ...

You can set a `style` attribute of the textarea:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import Textarea

class RulesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(
                           attrs={'rows': 1,
                                  'cols': 40,
                                  'style': 'height: 1em;'})},
    }
```

Works for me - tested on Firefox v. 23 and Chrome v. 29.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for `formfield_overrides`, didn't know about this feature =)

Comment: But this changes all the TextFields in the form what if I want to change some of them ?

Comment: if you need only one of them you may look for solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676970/2848256