# How to make a Django admin readonly textarea field

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin, if I have a model field that's a `TextField` and set it as readonly using `readonly_fields`, then it's displayed as text in a `<p>` tag.

I'd like it to still be displayed as a `textarea` field, but with its `disabled` attribute set.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

use a form field

```
   somefield = forms.CharField(
       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here's an idea (inspired by @cinoch`s answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1744292)) that does the trick for me, with a minimum of code:

1. **do not** add the name of your `TextField` to the `readonly_fields` in your `ModelAdmin` subclass (otherwise step 2 has no effect)
2. instead, **do** add the following to your `ModelAdmin` subclass:

   ```py
   formfield_overrides = {
       TextField: dict(widget=Textarea(attrs=dict(readonly=True)))
   }
   ```

Note this requires some imports:

```py
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.forms import Textarea
```

The `TextField` will now show up on the admin page as a scrollable `Textarea` instead of plain text, and its content will now be read-only, as desired.

Downside is that this applies to all `TextFields` in the model. If that's a problem, you should probably use a custom form [as suggested by @cinoch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33395230) and described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18738486) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176613).

Also, this has no effect if `ModelAdmin.has_change_permission()` returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

[@alasdair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394770) is actually quite clever, but, unfortunately, it does not provide an example.

Here's my attempt to clarify, based on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) for `readonly_fields`.

Assuming a model like so:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_textfield = models.TextField()
```

The admin could look like this, using [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) to create a readonly textarea:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['my_textfield']
    readonly_fields = ['display_my_textfield']
    
    @admin.display(description='my textfield')
    def display_my_textfield(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<textarea cols="40" rows="10" readonly>{}</textarea>',
            obj.my_textfield)
```

This also works if `ModelAdmin.has_change_permission()` returns `False`.

Comment: It would be good if this answer was more delineated, I'm not sure how to implement this and get it working.

Comment: @Conor: Not sure what more to tell. You need to import the required modules and register `MyModelAdmin` for `MyModel` as described in the [ModelAdmin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).

Comment: Yes it's fine, I think I understand the concept. I'm just wondering why you use exclude = ['my_textfield'], and then make a function to render a readonly textarea when it already becomes hidden in the admin panel

Comment: @Conor: See [@alasdair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394770) for that. If you don't use `exclude`, you will see two fields in the admin, one readonly and one that can be changed.

Comment: Ok I get it, I was thinking black and white about having just an empty text box. But it could be worthwhile to make any text readonly if that was the desire. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

The [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) can take method names as well as field names. You could write a method that renders the value of the field in a disabled textarea.

Make sure you exclude the field from the model admin, since it will no longer be in `readonly_fields`.