# How to customize a specific TextField inside the Django admin not all?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two `TextField` in my model. But i want to change the rows and cols attribute of only of the `TextField`. I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738486/control-the-size-textarea-widget-look-in-django-admin) page that the look of `TextField` can be changed using the following code in the `admin.py`.

```
class RulesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(
                       attrs={'rows': 1,
                              'cols': 40})},
}

...
admin.site.register(Rules, RulesAdmin)
```

As I said, using the above code changed the look of both the `TextField`, I want only to change one of those here is how my model looks like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    meta = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want only to change the look of `meta` field.

How should I go about this ?

Comment: this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) will help you to customize `TextField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to `forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from .models import Lesson

class PostModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'meta': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 5}),
        }
```

and in `admin.py` do this

```
class PostModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'pub_date', 'course',)
    search_fields = ('title', 'course__alias',)

    form = PostModelForm
```