# dojo textarea in firefox adds one extra row, how to fix with dijit.form.Textarea?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, xpages, dijit.form

I am using the dijit.form.Textarea module to create a dynamic textarea, so when I type the textarea is expanded automatically. works really great.

My problem is that Firefox browser seem to add one extra line by default so when the textarea is loaded in firefox the box is two lines high. while in chrome only one.

I tried google this and there seem to be others experiencing the same problem but have not found a good solution to this.

even if I remove the dojoType the area box is higher in Firefox then in Chrome so this seem to be Firefox default bahaviour and not a dojo issue

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea1" dojoType="dijit.form.Textarea"
        value="">
    </xp:inputTextarea>
</xp:view>
```

Adding the module in a theme:

```
<resources>
      <dojoModule>
       <name>dijit.form.Textarea</name>
      </dojoModule>
</resources>
```

Screenshot normal textarea

[image]

Screenshot dojo.form.textarea

[image]

How can I fix the problem firefox showing 2 lines by default when using dijit.form.Textarea?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you simply looking for the `rows` attribute?

```
<xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea1" rows="5" />
```

Comment: setting rows="1" does not help, firefox still always display min 2 lines

Comment: I see. The problem rests with Firefox and it has nothing to do with your XPage source code.

Comment: still looking for an xpages dojo workaround/solution though :-)

Comment: It's more of a css/javascript workaround. Have you seen this?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22700700/3256564

Comment: Use inspect in Firefox to browse (right click screen).  Select the icon to the left of `inspector` until it turns blue, place mouse pointer over the line you wish to see css for.