# How to make textarea content scroll horizontally on overflow in the same fashion as input? (without "jumps")

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, overflow

I'd like to use [one-line `textarea`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700700/3995261) (with `rows=1` and `overflow-x:hidden;`) but for now I have a problem: unlike `input type="text"`, when it is overflown horizontally, the content is scrolled with "jumps" when we continue typing inside it:

[image]

which is not nice for typing workflow (see also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywvat/110/)). Is there some simple way to fix this (ideally with just CSS), or the only way is to set an `on('input',..)` handler, check if we reached the end of the line inside it by some pesky pixel calculation and then set horizontal scroll position of the `textarea`?

Comment: You could use `<input>` instead of `<textarea>`.

Comment: @Alexander for my purpose it's a very awkward solution since I need it to become multiline at certain events, so I'm trying to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily achieved by using the `white-space` css attribute:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: hidden; /* don't add this if you want a scrollbar to appear */
```

Comment: Beatiful solution, great, thanks! How did you figure this?)

Comment: The default behavior of `textarea` when it reaches the end of the line is to put text on the next line (when it's big enough). I figured it's doing the same thing, but you are only being shown the last line, which is why you see the text at the start of the input and nothing else that was previously entered -- presumably if everything were to stay on the same line, it'd behave the same way an `input` field does.. and it did!