# sizing a textarea with CSS vs with cols and rows

Tags: html, textarea

What's the difference between sizing a textarea with cols and rows and sizing a textarea with height and width?

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="73" rows="12">with cols rows</textarea>
<textarea id="TextArea2" style="height:200px; width:600px";>with CSS</textarea>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVUEE/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/is-it-better-to-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attr)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cols` and `rows` are relative to font size.  `height` and `width` aren't.

http://jsfiddle.net/rVUEE/1/

**EDIT:**  Saying they are relative to "font size" is a bit too simplistic.  They take into account things such as `line-height` and `letter-spacing` if explicitly set as well.

Comment: `cols` is not relative to font size, and neither is `rows`, really (`rows` is relative to line height).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  What is `cols` relative to then?  I guess it's a really a combination of `font-size` and `letter-spacing`?

Answer (score 5):

1. The `cols` and `rows` attributes were required by HTML specifications. W3C HTML5 (approved in 2014) made them optional, but with impractical default values (20 and 2).
2. The attributes take effect even when CSS is disabled.
3. On the other hand, the attributes “lose” if dimensions are also specified in CSS.
4. The `rows` attribute specifies the height in terms of lines (effectively, with the line height as implied unit), and the `cols` attribute specifies the width in terms of “average” character width, a very vague concept, interpreted very differently by browsers. In CSS, any CSS units can be used and must be explicitly specified.

Comment: `cols` and `rows` are no longer required in the html5 spec.

Comment: -1 The `rows` and `cols` attributes are not required for the `textarea` element to pass HTML5 validation, nor are they listed as required by W3C.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't that different. The result will be (almost) the same.

I'm using most of the time max-width, min-width and the same for height. In new browsers like Chrome you can resize the textarea.

Comment: Textarea resizing can be disabled both in CSS and HTML.