# Height Percentage

Tags: html, css

I want to keep height of the textarea 50% of the frame's height in **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t2vwd/1/)**. If i resize the height of the result frame, textarea's height isn't change dynamically. How can i do that?

```
    html, body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


#text {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear:both;
}



#textArea {
    width: 95%;
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:50%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

    min-height:50%; /* real browsers */
    max-width: 902px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `!important` value in your `height: auto` property, so that `auto` is always going to override anything else you try to apply to `height`.

Comment: That's incorrect. Specifying width and height override rows and columns in all instances where CSS is supported. Rows and columns will only control the size of the textarea when CSS is not supported. Clarification can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/how-do-you-size-a-textarea).

Answer (score 0):

change the css

```
#textArea {
        width: 95%;
        height:50% !important;     
        min-height:50%; 
        max-width: 902px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```