# width:100% stretches to the border - textarea

Tags: html, css

I have `width:100%` for a textarea, but my textarea stretches all the way to the page's border by default. Is there anyway to fix this?

I'm trying to make this responsive so that the textarea's maximum width is `cols="100"`, but it will also shrink if needed.

```css
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 resize: none;
    }
```

```html
<textarea cols="100" rows="10" name="savetext" id="savetext"></textarea>
```

Comment: please add your improvement.What you do and what you want?

Comment: Can you please elaborate by adding the relevant code you currently have?

Comment: you should add code what you tried or you will be down voted please be quick

Comment: It's probably to do with your HTML mark up. You embedded the textarea in your body, instead of a wrapper.

Comment: @sandipon I just edited it.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I just edited it.

Comment: width 100% of what? in absence of any fixed-width parent, it will use the body/viewport width. so, it is 100% of your body/viewport.

Comment: @sanojlawrence I just edited it.

Comment: @BramVanroy I just edited it.

Comment: @abhitalks I would like the width to be 100 columns wide just like how I stated it in the HTML code.

Comment: border:0;
width:calc(100% - 10px); #from padding or margin

Comment: So remove the `wdith:100%`. Keep the `cols=100`.

Comment: @MustafaMJalal I don't get it?

Comment: @abhitalks I did that before but it doesn't make the textarea responsive.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3dnxjdox/

Comment: @MustafaMJalal Setting the width to 100% will make it go to the edges of the page. I only want it to be 100 columns but responsive.

Comment: float: left; maybe... i don't really get ur quesion

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: 400px;` (px) instead of % with that I would suggest use 'class' or 'id' in html element, instead of writing style globally for html element(s)

Example:

```
<style>
.textarea{
 width:300px;
 height: 150px;
}
</style>

<textarea rows="3" cols="50" class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use This css

```
textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 61%;
    resize: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use rows/cols in case CSS is not supported; if you specify a width or height in your CSS, they override the value derived from rows/cols.

[Should I size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You want it to be `cols="100"`, but you also want it to shrink when the viewport gets smaller.

Instead of `width: 100%` (which will override the `cols` attribute), use `max-width: 100%`. The textarea max width will be its specified column value, and it will also shrink if needed.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="100"></textarea>
```