# Textarea cols attribute with Bootstrap form-control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

Can someone clarify the following?
If I am using a `textarea` HTML input where I understand I can provide

- `rows` *Specifies the visible **number of lines** in a text area*
- `cols` *Specifies the visible **width** of a text area*

From [Textarea Tag Doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

If I am using textarea with Boostrap's `form-control` class, the width will be overriden to 100% so the `cols` attribute won't be used at all. Am I right? Is that the case in "all popular" browsers? Are there any special cases or I can just skip the `cols` attribute.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes