# How do I have elements move aside when I resize a textarea box in CSS?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a very simple site with a textarea on the left, and some text on the right. However if the user resizes the textarea, it clips over the text. How do I define a minimum distance that the text must stay from the textarea? Currently I simply have:

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 60px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: use 2 divs to define the area. Put textarea in left div and put text in the right div. And overflow hidden the first div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. That post is about how to set a default size, I'm asking about the user resizing it with the mouse.

Comment: Ashiqur Rahman that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position of your text might be causing the problem. Try removing position attribute. Hope it works fine

Comment: No, then the text doesn't move at all.

Answer (score 0):

Give your text position relative.

`.text { position: relative;}`

Or remove the users ability to resize the text area.

Comment: No, then there's a large gap where the text would normally be, plus it doesn't actually fix the resizing problem.