# how to increase height of textarea according to number of lines by jquery (in mobile view of webpage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, textarea

I have a text area in which i want to increase height of it according to lines which will be added by user.

i have tried these:

```
$("#chatroom").css({
  'max-height': 'auto',
  'height': 32',
  'width': auto',
  'overflow': 'auto',
  'margin-bottom': 11,
});
```

Comment: post your html and css. Is the tag <textarea>. text area height is controlled using rows attribute. You can add event lisnteners to change event, and in there update the rows attribute value

Comment: check answers in this thread also.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes

Comment: I have user emojionearea which is not allowing me to resize by rows. In emojionearea every element is reacted as <textarea> whether yo are useing textbox, button, div etc.

Comment: I would suggest you update such details in question name and description. Good luck