# How to increase height of textarea using bootstrap rows and columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a form in which I have two items in a row, like this:

**My output**

[image]

**Code** that I used:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">  <!-- [1, 0] -->
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label id="fieldTitle">Equipment Length</label>
            <select id="selectOption" class="form-control" required data-error="Please select Equipment Length"></select>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">  <!-- [1, 1] -->
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label id="fieldTitle">Customer Notes</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Please write customer notes" ng-model="myTextarea" required data-error="Please enter customer notes"></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"> {{myTextarea}} </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

> So, please guide me how do I increase the height of the textarea just like my

**desired output**
[image]
please tell me how do I do it.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `<textarea>` `rows` attribute?

Comment: Use **`rows - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp`** attribute of `textarea`

Comment: V3 or V4 of bootstrap

Comment: <textarea  rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Please write customer notes" ng-model="myTextarea" required data-error="Please enter customer notes">
                </textarea>

Comment: @E-housmaMardini Yes I tried rows attribute, but it's not working.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: you need to show us full CSS code and try to make a working snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

adjust as needed.

Comment: @core114 are you insinuating that I plagiarized? are you sure it's not a complete coincidence that I used that same values?

Comment: @core114 In cases like this with a small piece of code it's unlikely that it's actual plagiarized. In comparison, when a greater part of code (let's say 15+ lines) is completely identical, it's very likely that it's plagiarism. But always asume good faith first.

Answer (score 49):

With Bootstrap 4 you will need to have the property rows and add "height: 100%;" so that the height would stretch to the number of rows specified. "rows" along does not work.

```html
<textarea rows="10" style="height:100%;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Same answer as @Noriel but 8 month later

Comment: Perhaps, though I see that 100px is quite different that 100% in terms of results. Nevertheless, I would leave this for newbies...

Comment: `h-100` on Bootstrap, FYI

Answer (score 14):

In HTML set

```
<textarea rows="10"></textarea>
```

In CSS set

```
textarea { height: 100px; }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

the class **form-control** remove textarea rows attribute so just replace it with **col-md-12**

```
<textarea class="col-md-12" placeholder="Please write customer notes" ng-model="myTextarea" required data-error="Please enter customer notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: That happened to me. Why is that? I have styles depending on form-control. Is there another way?

Answer (score 11):

With Bootstrap 4 you will need to add h-25 class

```
<textarea class="form-control h-25" rows="5" placeholder="Please write customer notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what that class does and why adding it helps

Comment: h-25 means 25% of parent element height

Answer (score 1):

Not a big fan of changing globally the textarea css attr.

Would rather use a specific css class, but it could be overriden by some other classes, so you could use the `!important`, even tho it is not a best practice.

```
{{ form_widget(form.myTextarea,{'attr': {'class': 'specific-textarea'}}) }}
```

And add in your CSS

```
.specific-textarea { height: 200px !important; }
```