# textarea height not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

I have a modal dialog in my ASP.NET Web application using the following code:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="mdlNewNote" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mdlNewNoteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="mdlNewNoteLabel">Add New Note</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <form class="was-validated" id="frmNote" name="frmNote" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-floating col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="NoteBody" name="NoteBody"></textarea>
                                        <label for="NoteBody">Notes</label>                                    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In that block there is a `<textarea>` element that I want to be sized inside the modal according to its row count, which is set at 10.  However, it only actually displays three rows in the modal, as shown below:

[image: What modal looks like in browser]

How do I fix it so that the `<textarea>` element is as tall as it should be (based on number of rows it is given) rather than the 3 rows it shows now?

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap, you have to override the height by using:

```css
.specific-textarea { height: 100% !important; }
```

cf:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398265/12172974

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML for textarea sizing.

```
<label for="story">Tell us your story:</label>

<textarea id="story" name="story"
          rows="5" cols="33">
It was a dark and stormy night...
</textarea>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: I am doing that already, but it isn't working right.  See the code I provided.

Comment: Reduce the beginning row number from 10 to 5?

Comment: I had it set to 5 to begin with and it didn't work then.  I think the answer is to not wrap it in a ```<div>``` tag.  Then it seems to work as it should.