# How to expand textarea?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to expand textarea but it isn't working with margin-top like this:

```css
#sqlcontainerLoggedInPage2 {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="sqlcontainerLoggedInPage2">
  <textarea id="diary" class="form-control"><?php echo $diaryContent; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: if you want to expand textarea shouldnt you add more height to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I size a textarea with CSS width / height or HTML cols / rows attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes)

Comment: it worked, but is there a way of doing it with margin and/or padding?

Comment: paddings and margins are outside the content. You can increase them, but the space for the content will stay the same unless you change width/height

Comment: You aren't even setting a margin on the textarea; you added it to the container div

Answer (score 0):

`height` cannot be set using `margin`.

If you want the `textarea` to take up all of the height of its parent element, then the parent element must have its `height` set to a definitive amount and then the `textarea` can have its `height` set to `100%`.

```css
#sqlcontainerLoggedInPage2 {
  height: 60px;
}

textarea { height:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="sqlcontainerLoggedInPage2">
  <textarea id="diary" class="form-control">
   <?php echo $diaryContent;?>
  </textarea>
</div>
```