# scroll to top in textarea below fixed div

Tags: html, css, position, textarea, css-position

Situation:

1. There is a textarea that is taller than the browser window (and full of text).
2. There is a `position:fixed;` bar at the top.
3. When the text in the textarea is edited and scrolled down and the user scrolls back to the top of the textarea with the cursor keys, the top of the text area stays hidden behind the "bar at the top".

**Question: How can the layout be changed (HTML, CSS) so that the first lines of the textarea become visible through keystrokes inside the text area?**

I have tried:

- adding margin or padding to textarea
- adding margin or padding to div containing textarea
- adding padding to body element

To be clear: some of these measures help that the whole text area becomes visible when the mouse is used to scroll to the top. The textarea should be accessible fully through the cursor keys on the keyboard.

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxg4anaf/)

Comment: I don't believe that is possible, since the "menu" is "fixed", but try changing the z-index on the textarea.

Comment: Thanks @Kup. I don't take "it's impossible" for an answer! ;-) z-index won't do any good. The fixed div is a top bar and needs to be there and on the top and visible at all times.

Comment: I understand, I also don't like the "impossible answer" :) but in this case I'm afraid you don't have much choice. But if you can find a workaround this, I would also like to know it ;)

Comment: I'm curious to know why you would need a `<textarea>` as you have described. Sounds like a whole lot of issues down the road if it needs to be responsive etc.

Comment: what else than a textarea, @hungerstar? `contenteditable` is not an option due to cross-browser/backward compatibility. What else could I use?

Comment: @SwissMister I didn't say, _"Don't use a `<textarea>`."_ I asked, _"Why would you need a `<textarea>` as you have described?"_ I've never seen a ridiculously tall and narrow textarea before like you have in your jsFiddle and I was curious as to what it's final usage/purpose will be.

Comment: @hungerstar example: https://shrib.com. The point is to have a browser that is exactly like the notepad.exe text editor in microsoft windows.

Comment: Ah, shrib.com is a bit different from your jsFiddle example. They are adding a scroll bar and are managing the height of the `<textarea>` with JS. From your post it looks like you are attempting to avoid either of those implementations.

Comment: Very attentive! In fact, I am using http://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant to make the textarea grow in size, but with the same end result as they have on shrib.com. So, for the situation in question, it is adequate to set a tall height on the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/dxg4anaf/4/

```
.text {
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Making scrollable just the div with textarea, not the container of both that div and the top div. The padding between textarea and its top would still not be visible when you scroll with keyboard, but at least all of the textarea will.

Can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

add default `rows` and cols `size`

`<textarea rows="20" cols="50">
first line
..
..
</textarea>`

and remove `height:10000px;` in css of textarea

```
textarea {
   margin-top:30px;
   height:10000px;
}
```

css should be like

```
textarea { margin-top:30px;}
```

Comment: Thank you - but this does not solve the issue at all. I would not recommend to step from CSS back to the dark old days of HTML rows and cols... http://stackoverflow.com/a/21280976/1598477